# Immutable.js - Passing ReferenceError: Map is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, immutable.js

I just found out about immutable.js.
I want to play around with it, get used to how it works.
Really simple. Don't even need to write code, just futzing with
it in the node shell interactively.

I have installed it:

```
$ npm install immutable
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/xxxxxxx/node/immutable/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/xxxxxxx/node/immutable/package.json'
npm WARN immutable No description
npm WARN immutable No repository field.
npm WARN immutable No README data
npm WARN immutable No license field.

+ immutable@3.8.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 1 package in 2.934s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

...and then I attempt to work with it.

```
$ node
> const { Map } = require('immutable');
ReferenceError: Map is not defined
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:683:37)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
$ node -v
v10.10.0
$ npm -v 
6.4.1
```

A little assistance in making sense of what I may have missed would be really cool.

TIA

**UPDATE:**
Just for the heck of it I tried this:

```
$ sudo npm install immutable
```

And now it works
???

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: https://i.imgur.com/Gk97QjP.png

Comment: ok. What version of node/npm you have?

Comment: node v9.8.0 / npm 5.6.0